# Read PDF and send via FTP in Python

Tags: python, urllib2, ftplib

Usecase : I am trying to read pdf from url and then send it via FTP

I have functions as:

```
def send_via_ftp(self, url, filename, ftp_site, username, password, directory):

    import urllib2
    try:
        data = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    except urllib2.URLError, e:
        print "Failed to fetch content: %s" % e
        return False
    except urllib2.HTTPError, e:
        print "HTTP ERROR: %s" % e
        return False

    return self.send_file_by_ftp(data, ftp_site, username, password, directory, filename)
```

## -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
def send_file_by_ftp(self, data, ftp_site, username, password, directory, filename):          

    import ftplib
    try:
        remote_ftp_connection = ftplib.FTP(ftp_site)
    except ftplib.all_errors as e:
        print str(e)
        return False
    else:
        remote_ftp_connection.login(username, password)
        try:
            if len(directory):
                remote_ftp_connection.cwd(directory)
            remote_ftp_connection.storbinary("STOR %s" % filename, data)
        except ftplib.error_perm,e:
            print str(e)
            return False
        else:
            remote_ftp_connection.quit()
            return True
```

My call looks like:
send_via_ftp("http://url/***.pdf",  "XYZ.pdf", "ftp url 192.168.0.101", "XXXX", "YYYYY", "")

The file is successfully made in the FTP folder but the content in the file are not written. While I open it says "Format Error: Not a pdf or corrupted".
What could be the problem? Many thanks for any help

Comment: Did you try to separate it: first download, control the downloaded file, and next send?

Comment: Now this looks strange...When I use python shell and run above command one by one, it works fine...Any one knows why is this not working in above code?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're passing `data` as the second parameter to `remote_ftp_connection.storbinary`, but it should be `ftp_data`.  Not sure why you aren't getting a `NameError` exception.

Answer (score 0):

Since FTP uses file-like object, the following modification worked for me.

```
def send_via_ftp(self, url, filename, ftp_site, username, password, directory):

import urllib2
try:
    from cStringIO import StringIO
except:
    from StringIO import StringIO

try:
    data = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    data_ = StringIO(data.read())
    data_.seek(0)
except urllib2.URLError, e:
    print "Failed to fetch content: %s" % e
    return False
except urllib2.HTTPError, e:
    print "HTTP ERROR: %s" % e
    return False
else:
    content = data_.read()

return self.send_file_by_ftp(content, ftp_site, username, password, directory, filename)
```

================================================================================

```
def send_file_by_ftp(self, data, ftp_site, username, password, directory, filename):          

    import ftplib
    try:
        from cStringIO import StringIO
    except:
        from StringIO import StringIO
    try:
        remote_ftp_connection = ftplib.FTP(ftp_site)
    except ftplib.all_errors as e:
        print str(e)
        return False
    else:
        remote_ftp_connection.login(username, password)
        try:
            if len(directory):
                remote_ftp_connection.cwd(directory)
            remote_ftp_connection.storbinary("STOR %s" % filename, StringIO(data))
        except ftplib.error_perm,e:
            print str(e)
            return False
        else:
            remote_ftp_connection.quit()
            return True
```